# What is the html to make a sound effect of balloon popping on rollover?

Tags: html, adobe, muse

I study graphics as one of my subjects at school. Currently, my task is to make a website for a party so I have started to create the homepage. The home page has four balloons on it and when you roll over them they pop. But, what I also want them to do is to play a balloon popping sound effect when you roll over them and they pop.

However, I cant work out what the HTML would be to achieve this.

The website: partybox.businesscatalyst.com

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Also, Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I have tried this code <img src="balloon-animation-2.gif" data-srcover="rollover.jpg" data-soundover="sound.mp3, sound.ogg">

Comment: Put the code ***inside*** the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done efficiently using only HTML, as it will require the use of `<audio>` as in

```
<audio autoplay>
    <source src="file.wav" type="audio/wav"><!--file.wav will replace your sound file with the pop effect-->
</audio>
```

However, the `<audio>` still required to be started (in case of `controls`) or dynamically created (in case of `autoplay`) - which will still require JavaScript.

A simpler JavaScript method would be like - on your `onclick` or `onhover` function, simply add this JavaScript Code:

```
var sound = new Audio("file.wav"); //file.wav will replace your sound file with the pop effect
sound.play(); //Play the sound
```

Comment: but i can only use html

Comment: Can you use `onhover` attribute?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, can you do this: `<element onhover="/*some Js*/">`

Comment: can only use html

Comment: You obviously cannot do that with plain HTML. This is because when you used `data-srcover`, it worked because the element was `<img>` with `src`. That's the reason `data-soundover` didn't work because `<img>` has no `sound` attribute!

Comment: I guess your question should be closed as off topic